# Vue.Js with Firebase cloud firestore, adding items to database is triggered twice

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to send an Item to my database collection in firestore, for some reason the `add()` function gets executed twice so the same object is sent two times with different autogenerated Id, which is obviously not the desired behavior, below is the file from which I initialize my firebase app.

```js
 import firebase from 'firebase'
 
 // Initialize Firebase
 var config = {
    apiKey: "**********",
    authDomain: "*******",
    databaseURL: "https://*****.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-****",
    storageBucket: "****.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "*******"
  };
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

  export default firebase.firestore()
```

now this code below is how i trigger the `add()` function to send the item to the database from my .vue file

```js
import db from '../firebase/init.js';

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    addNewItem(){
      let item = {
        row1: 'record one,
        row2: 'record two,
      }
      
      db.collection('myItems').push(item)
        .then(doc => console.log(doc))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
  }
}
```

please let me know in a comment below if any additional information is needed for better clarifying the issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a code sample for where this method is being called from in the html template?

Comment: sure, this method is triggered via a click event from a button within a form, and the object data that i send to the database, is actually coming from an object in  my data function that is bound to the form input fields, a regular vue two-way binding

Comment: actually your question allowed me to look again at the html template, i did find the issue, in the `<form>` tags i added the `@submit.prevent="addNewItem"` attribute, then i discovered that i triggered the same function via click event in the button itself. so thats why the function got executed twice.. i removed triggereing the function from the button and its working properly now, thanks very much :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)